# What is the impact of individual estimate on each other in matrix inversion?

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-inverse, inverse-problems, inverse-series

I am looking to understand the impact of each estimate on each other in matrix inversion.

Lets say I have a vector $A = \left[a_1, a_2 \right]^T$ of size $2 \times 1$ and $a_1$ and $a_2$ are related as $a_2 = \frac{d}{dt} a_1$,
matrix $C$ of size $M \times 2$ and vector $B$ of size $M \times 1$.

The matrix inversion of least square sense,

\begin{eqnarray}
     A &=& (C^\mathrm{H}C)^{-1}C^\mathrm{H} B \nonumber \\
\end{eqnarray}

$C$ matrix has two columns, where the first column is very very large in magnitude than the second column. So during inversion, the $a_2$ in $A$ vector is very much amplified and $a_1$ in $A$ vector has a small error than the ground truths.

Now I am looking to understand, what exactly the reason behind this problem of estimates $a_1$ and $a_2$. I understand the error of $a_2$ which is due to the weak second column in matrix $C$. But why there is an error on $a_1$?

1. Can anyone help me to understand this mathematical theory?
2. During the inversion of matrix are estimates estimated independently or dependent?
3. Is it the high amplification of $a_2$ is influencing the error on $a_1$?